# Using Vectors in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

How can you define add or subtract vectors in NetLogo. It doesn't seem to have any datatype pertaining to it.

By vectors I here am talking in terms specifically velocity of a turtle.

Are there any extensions in netlogo that support this, I can't find any.

Comment: I don't understand well but have you take a look on the gis extension? [http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/gis.html]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of an extension that provides vectors. But the math involved to code it in NetLogo itself is generally not that complicated. So for example suppose you choose to represent a two-dimensional vector as a list of two numbers. Then:

```
to-report vector-add [v1 v2]
  report (list (first v1 + first v2) (last v1 + last v2))
end

observer> show vector-add [0.1 0.2] [0.5 0.3]
observer: [0.6 0.5]
```

`vector-add` can also be written as:

```
to-report vector-add [v1 v2]
  report (map + v1 v2)
end
```

which works on vectors of any dimension.