# Using Vectors in NetLogo (Not Constant)

Tags: vector, netlogo

I plan to use vectors to represent positions (xcor ycor) of many turtles that are randomly created.
I tried NetLogo Matrix Extension aslo the method as below:
[Using Vectors in NetLogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962986/using-vectors-in-netlogo)

However, both of them require constant values.
How can I represent (xcor ycor) as vector?

Thanks

Comment: Please add some code of what you arleady have and already tried, so people on stackoverflow can halp you better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a list:

```
to test
  ca
  crt 25 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  print [list xcor ycor] of turtles
end
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, I still need to input those vector to a function including other vectors one by one. Any advise?

Comment: Why do you believe you cannot use a list instead?

Comment: I try to use NetLogo Matrix Extension with list:    
        ask particles[
        let candi other particles with [distance myself <  20]
        if any? candi[
        ask candi[
        set m1 [list xcor ycor] of self
        set m2 [list xcor ycor] of myself
        set ndi matrix:minus m1 m2
        print ndi                                                                                                                     However, it doesn't work. A runtime error "Inputs must be matrices or numbers but  found a class org.nlogo.api.LogoList" occurs. Any advise? Thanks