# Issue with Calculating Perpendicular Distance in NetLogo

Tags: vector, linear-algebra, netlogo, distance, map-projections

I'm working on a NetLogo model where I'm trying to connect new "call" turtles to the closest edge defined by two "node" turtles in a network. To achieve this, I'm using the perpendicular-distance function to calculate the perpendicular distance from a call to a line defined by two nodes. However, I'm encountering an issue with the implementation. Below is my dummy code, the attempted solution, and the explanation of the problem:

```
breed [nodes node]
breed [calls call]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-nodes 15 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color gray
  ]
  
  ask nodes [
    create-links-with nodes [
      set color gray
    ]
  ]
  
  create-calls 5 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  
  reset-ticks
end

to-report perpendicular-distance [point node1 node2]
  ; Calculate the perpendicular distance from a point to a line defined by two nodes
  let line-vector node2 - node1
  let point-to-node1 point - node1
  let projection (point-to-node1 * line-vector) / (line-vector * line-vector)
  let projected-point node1 + (projection * line-vector)
  report distance point projected-point
end

to connect-calls
  ask calls [
    let closest-edge nobody
    let min-distance 99999

    ask links [
      let start-node end1
      let end-node end2
      let perpendicular-dist [perpendicular-distance myself start-node end-node]

      if perpendicular-dist < min-distance [
        set min-distance perpendicular-dist
        set closest-edge self
      ]
    ]

    if closest-edge != nobody [
      let node-start-point-closest-edge end1
      let node-end-point-closest-edge end2

      ask node-start-point-closest-edge [
        create-link-with node-end-point-closest-edge [set color blue]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

**Attempted Solution:**

I tried using the perpendicular-distance function to calculate the perpendicular distance between a call and a line defined by two nodes. However, I encountered issues with the implementation. Specifically, I noticed that I cannot use perpendicular-distance within the context of a link, as it should be used within the context of a turtle. As a result, the code doesn't work as expected.

**Question:**

How to correctly calculate the perpendicular distance between a call and a line defined by two nodes in NetLogo? How should I adjust my code to properly use the perpendicular-distance function within the context of a turtle?

Comment: From the looks of the code, you are trying to subtract one turtle from another turtle. The turtles however are not just points and they can't be treated as such. If you want to do vector calculations, you will have to write the code for that yourself (or look it up on stackoverflow). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962986/using-vectors-in-netlogo is an example (But I just saw that you already reacted there so I mainly leave it here for reference for other people)

Comment: Just yesterday I wrote some code that calculates the linear equation of the line between two points (and then uses it to see which patches the line crosses). I think you will want to do something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565308/copy-the-link-breed-variable-in-the-patch-below/76947586#76947586.

Comment: See also the intersecting lines and intersecting links models in the model library for more examples using linear equations